# JPA 2.0 issue on Websphere 7.0 using RSA 8.5

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having issues with getting my application running with JPA 2.0 on WAS 7.0. I am using RSA 8.5 for development. I am using Hibernate as the provider.
Here is what I have done so far:

1. I configured my project with JPA 2.0 facet.
2. added all the hibernate "required" jars and the jpa jar to the build
   path as well as in the manifest entry.
3. I followed this article: [Alternate JPA Providers in WebSphere
   Application Server](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/form/anonymous/api/wiki/53181ccd-bcd4-431f-b968-0b5f6d46d652/page/192a432b-28bb-4080-b037-345e5d83da76/attachment/61e74f67-1d60-4120-ba25-ad7264c9f4f6/media/alternatejpaproviders_testreport.pdf)
   and I changed the default persistence provider via admin console, and I am seeing these lines in the logs at server startup:

   ```
   [12/6/13 9:36:20:529 EST] 00000000 JPAComponentI I   CWWJP0026I: The Java Persistence API (JPA) component is initializing.
   [12/6/13 9:36:20:537 EST] 00000000 JPAComponentI I   CWWJP0006I: The org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence class is loaded as the default Java Persistence API (JPA) provider.
   ```
4. This is my application's persistence.xml:

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
   > xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   > xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   > http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   > <persistence-unit name="biReconWeb">
   >   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   >   <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
   > value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory"/>         <property
   > name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
   > value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup"/>
   > ```
5. In the server, I created a shared library with the following jars and created a "application first" class loader referencing this shared lib:

antlr-2.7.7.jar

hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar

hibernate-core-4.2.7.SP1.jar

hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar

javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar

jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar

jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar

hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.SP1.jar

When I deploy the application, I am getting this error:

```
> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value
> '2.0' of    attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid
> with respect to the corresponding attribute use.Attribute 'version'
> has a fixed value of '1.0'.
```

If I change the persistence version to 1.0, the application starts OK. But I want to use JPA 2.0, can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

PS: One thing I have not done is I have not applied any JPA feature packs to my WAS (version 7.0.0). Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the JPA 1.0 libraries of WAS (loaded by the parent classloader) are trying to read the `persistence.xml` of your webapp and get confused by the version.

According to [this post](http://larims.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/jpa2-0-sous-websphere7/) (in French), you have to either install the OSGI & JPA 2.0 Feature Pack, or move your `persistence.xml` somewhere else than under `META-INF` so the JPA 1.0 libraries don't find it. You then need to load your `persistence.xml` using an alternative way, either programmatically or through Spring.

Comment: Thanks, that french post really helped.

Comment: I was already using Spring (org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) with <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"> to specify hibernate properties. And I decided not to use persistence.xml as this is a feature starting with spring 3.1.. Here is the excerpt from an article in dz:  `Starting with Spring 3.1, this XML file is no longer necessary – the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean now supports a ‘packagesToScan’ property where the packages to scan for @Entity classes can be specified.` Full article: [link]http://java.dzone.com/articles/persistence-layer-spring-31-0